# using external maps with bing map

Tags: bing-maps, esri

can i use bing map platform with an external mapping source ?
for example, i want to use bing map siverlight client with my own map files instead of the provided maps. (some areas coverage is insufficiant with bings provided mapping)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful tool you may want to utilize if you don't have ArcGIS Server is MapCruncher, which will take a raster image, allow you to georeference it and produce Virtual Earth compatible tiles.

If you need to display vector data, you can either convert it to a format like KML or use a product called SharpMap to render tiled images.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that since this was tagged ESRI, that you want a method to use ESRI products for your data sources...  There are a lot of ways you can create your own tiles and use them in Bing Maps.  If you have ESRI ArcGIS Server, you can use the [ESRI JS API](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/ve/) to add your own services to Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite TileSource class and override GetUri method